# How to resize the root space from 8GB to 40GB

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have below structure of partitions of my hard disk of 250GB. My root space is 8GB, which is increasingly becoming very congested. Can you suggest a way to increase my root space?

[image]

Comment: ...the disk is pretty full. More than deleting some swap to extend /dev/sda8 (of a mere 2 to 4 G) I see little solution short of adding another disk...

Comment: You can't very well expand a partition without any free space, or indicating what existing partitions you are willing to give up.

Comment: Windows NTFS partitions work best with 30% free space and become extremely slow when space is below 10% free. You need more space, either larger drive or another drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do I see 3 swaps?

If you want to increase root you need unallocated space adjecent to that partition.

So

- backup the files from either /home/videos/ and/or /home/songs/ to an external disc (I see no method of keeping these files on the system while doing a resizing. See the warning below too).
- delete sda3, sda7, sda9. More than 1 swap space is pointless. I assume sda3 is not used and sda9 is the current active swap? (might be worth an extra check)
- delete sda5 and/or sda6 to get 6 + (40) + (40) for a max 86Gb
- resize sda8 to the size you want (btw. 15Gb for a desktop with no server software is more than enough (if you create a separate home). 15Gb is unlikely to let you run out of space on / and a /home makes it easier to move stuff around.
- recreate a new swap partition. I would make it 4Gb
- recreate either /home/videos and/or /home/songs/ and move the files back.

A warning:  resizing partitions that are near full takes -a lot- of time. I would serriously consider to clean out all the partitions on sda4 that are not root and put the files you need to save on an external disc, clean out all the partitions and then make a 40Gb root.

And another problem: you do realize you can NOT put the total contents of videos and songs back to a new NTFS partition if you increase your root to 40Gb. You only have about 20Gb to play with.

Comment: ah crap :D I looked at the wrong column

Comment: @Cornelius I refrain from commenting on that :-D

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete `sda5`
2. Create 4 GB `swap` at the end of the free space
3. Delete the two `swap` of 2 GB
4. Resize `sda8` to fill all empty space